# What is b*, b**, b*** in linear algebra?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, notation, vectors

[image]

In question 2.1 B point 2, it says, **Take the dot product of each column of A ( and also b) with y= ( 1, 1, -1).**

Now If i do dot product, A.y = (-1, 6, 5) and b.y = (4, 5, 8), I got two column vectors as output. Now in solution of this question says, A.y = 0 and b.y = 1(non-zero). But According to my calculation, I don't see such output. What I am missing here?

And from point 3, what is **b***,  **b****,  **b***** means?

Comment: They are just symbols for variables. One can just as well have written $b_1,b_2,b_3$ or $b_A,b_B,b_C$. The *'s have no operational meaning here.

Comment: Usually $V^*$ denotes the dual space to a vector space $V$. But here the star is just used as an upper index.

Comment: I actually used this textbook and I don’t remember ever learning about a meaning of superscript asterisks, which suggests that Winther and Dietrich Burde are correct.

Comment: I got the point, thank you all